# Prevent one of the logging handlers for specific messages

Tags: python, logging, handler

I monitor my script with the `logging` module of the Python Standard Library and I send the loggings to both the console with `StreamHandler`, and to a file with `FileHandler`.

I would like to have the option to disable a handler for a `LogRecord` *independantly of its severity*. For example, for a specific `LogRecord` I would like to have the option not to send it to the file destination or to the console (with passing a parameter).

I have found that the library has the `Filter` class for that reason (which is described as a finer grained way to filter blocks), but haven't figured out how to do it.

Any ideas how to do this in a cosistent way?

Comment: You don't need a `Filter` class, you can just use a function as mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it is quite easy. I used a function as a `Handler.filer` as suggested in the comments.

This is a working example:

```
from pathlib import Path
import logging
from logging import LogRecord


def build_handler_filters(handler: str):

    def handler_filter(record: LogRecord):
        if hasattr(record, 'block'):
            if record.block == handler:
                return False
        return True

    return handler_filter


ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.addFilter(build_handler_filters('console'))
fh = logging.FileHandler(Path('/tmp/test.log'))
fh.addFilter(build_handler_filters('file'))

mylogger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
mylogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
mylogger.addHandler(ch)
mylogger.addHandler(fh)
```

When the logger is called, the message is sent to both console and output, i.e.

`mylogger.info('msg')`.

To block for example the file the logger should be called with the `extra` argument like this

`mylogger.info('msg only to console', extra={'block': 'file'})`

Disabling console is analogous.